# Git Merge and mergetool for large files

Tags: git, vim

I've a problem when working with large project where many people edit the same file then commit and push into `HEAD/MASTER`. Due to the speed of update it seems everytime I tried to pull from git it always ask gitmerge and I had to go through the entire file to edit the `HEAD >>>>>` and the `log ID`. I was wondering if there is a easier way to delete mutiple section of `HEAD >>>>` and end with `log ID` through out the file if I already know what to edit in the file. I am also wondering if it is possible not to generate `.orig` file everytime gitmerge is finished?

Comment: Tim Pope has some nice plugins that might be of interest to you [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) and [Unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no simpler way to go through each of the `HEAD >>>>>`.

Regarding the `.orig` files, you can turn them off, using

```
git config --global mergetool.keepBackup false
```

Answer (score 1):

My [ConflictMotions plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3991) provides movement commands and text objects to go to and operate on conflicting lines, as indicated by Git and many other revision control systems. With the `:ConflictTake` command, you can quickly resolve a conflict.